# Why doesn't WebRequest.AllowAutoRedirect redirect the initial url to the correct download url?

Tags: c#, redirect, httpwebrequest

I am testing a url which is expected to redirect automatically to file download url.
But it doesn't be redirected to the correct url that is https://s51.workupload.com/download/zMR4vIPW.
How can I make it works?

```
public static void Main()
{
    string url = "https://workupload.com/start/zMR4vIPW";
    HttpWebRequest req = WebRequest.Create(url) as HttpWebRequest;
    req.UserAgent = "Mozilla"; //Dummy useragent assigned
    HttpWebResponse response = req.GetResponse() as HttpWebResponse;

    //Expected url is https://s51.workupload.com/download/zMR4vIPW but it doesn't give that url
    Console.WriteLine("Redirected url: " + response.ResponseUri.OriginalString);

    foreach(var item in response.Headers.AllKeys)
        Console.WriteLine(response.Headers[item]);

}
```

**The output:**

> Redirected url: https://workupload.com/file/zMR4vIPW
>
> Accept-Encoding
>
> 3545 max-age=0, no-cache, must-revalidate text/html; charset=UTF-8
>
> Wed, 19 Feb 2020 19:30:54 GMT token=vdm35dfet0majftiosl236c1a7;
>
> expires=Thu, 20-Feb-2020 01:30:54 GMT; Max-Age=21600; path=/;
>
> domain=.workupload.com; HttpOnly Apache

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This solution should be working for your case:

```cs
using Newtonsoft.Json;
using System;
using System.IO;
using System.Net;
using System.Text;

namespace ConsoleApp1
{
    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            string fileId = "zMR4vIPW";
            string userAgent = "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/80.0.3987.116 Safari/537.36";

            HttpWebRequest request;
            HttpWebResponse response;

            // 1: Get cookie from this request
            request = WebRequest.Create("https://workupload.com/file/" + fileId) as HttpWebRequest;
            request.UserAgent = userAgent;

            response = request.GetResponse() as HttpWebResponse;

            string setHeaderCookieValue = response.Headers["Set-Cookie"];
            string tokenCookieKeyValue = setHeaderCookieValue.Substring(0, setHeaderCookieValue.IndexOf(';'));

            response.Close();

            // 2: Trick the web server into thinking it's a real user request
            request = WebRequest.Create("https://workupload.com/start/" + fileId) as HttpWebRequest;
            request.UserAgent = userAgent;
            request.Headers["Cookie"] = tokenCookieKeyValue;

            response = request.GetResponse() as HttpWebResponse;
            response.Close();

            // 3: Call API to get file download URL
            request = WebRequest.Create("https://workupload.com/api/file/getDownloadServer/" + fileId) as HttpWebRequest;
            request.UserAgent = userAgent;
            request.Headers["Cookie"] = tokenCookieKeyValue;

            response = request.GetResponse() as HttpWebResponse;

            // 4: Get file download URL from JSON response
            using (Stream jsonStream = response.GetResponseStream())
            using (StreamReader jsonStreamReader = new StreamReader(jsonStream, Encoding.UTF8))
            {
                string responseString = jsonStreamReader.ReadToEnd();
                string downloadUrl = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<dynamic>(responseString).data.url;

                response.Close();

                Console.WriteLine("Download URL: " + downloadUrl);

                // 5: Download the actual file
                request = WebRequest.Create(downloadUrl) as HttpWebRequest;
                request.UserAgent = userAgent;
                request.Headers["Cookie"] = tokenCookieKeyValue;

                response = request.GetResponse() as HttpWebResponse;

                using (Stream dataStream = response.GetResponseStream())
                using (MemoryStream memoryStream = new MemoryStream())
                {
                    dataStream.CopyTo(memoryStream);

                    byte[] fileContent = memoryStream.ToArray();

                    // For debugging purpose only, use FileStream for saving file to disk
                    File.WriteAllBytes("testing.rar", fileContent);
                }

                response.Close();
            }

            Console.WriteLine("Press any key to continue...");
            Console.ReadKey();
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: I am gonna test your solution but i want to ask something before. Is it always needed to call an api and parsing json data to be redirected to the download url? I know some other websites that has redirection to the download url, my code also doesn't work for those, e.g. https://www.gezginler.net/indir/gimp.html . I was expecting the AllowAutoRedirect to work for all redirection operations automatically but it isn't. What cases does it work for?

Comment: API calling is site specific, different websites work differently, depending on their system design. For this specific website (workupload.com), it seems to fetch file URL from their API and then set browser's URL in JavaScript to trigger file download. Some other file download sites might be checking (or not checking) HTTP headers like (Cookie, Host, Referer, User-Agent, etc) before deciding to redirect to actual file download URL or redirect to other URL. The conclusion is, we can't always rely on AllowAutoRedirect to work on every websites.