# C# - Cannot Open Dowloaded RAR or ZIP File

Tags: c#

Need Your Help. 
When i downloaded myself it opening but when i downloading with c# windows form it Downloading Successfully but not opening,
am using this code to download Rar or Zip File.

```
private void downloadBtn_Click(object sender, EventArgs e) 
{
    WebClient client = new WebClient();
    string tAddress = "Download Link"; // When i Downloaded mySelf it Worked And Opened
    string fileName = "Testfile.Zip";
    Uri uri = new Uri(tAddress);
    client.DownloadFileCompleted += Client_DownloadFileCompleted;
    client.DownloadFileAsync(uri, fileName);

}
private void Client_DownloadFileCompleted(object sender, AsyncCompletedEventArgs e)
{
    MessageBox.Show("Download Completed Successfully!");
}
```

This is Error When I Trying To Open Rar Or Zip File.
[It Says Error, This File Has Incorrect Format Or Damaged, But When I Try To Download Myself Its Opened](https://i.stack.imgur.com/BLg5M.png)

Comment: How does the size of the file compare when you download it yourself vs when downloaded with this code?

Comment: how are you opening the file and where is it completed i do not see any `await` are you simply missing `await client.DownloadFileAsync(uri, fileName);` otherwise change to `client.DownloadFile(uri, fileName);`

Comment: @Code Stranger when i downloaded myself size is 3MB and with code is 150kb, i dont know whats happening\

Comment: @Seabizkit when i trying `await client.DownloadFileAsync(uri, fileName)` or `await client.DownloadFile(uri, fileName)` it brings me error, can you give me code how to do it?

Comment: @GuKkA to confrim it works it would be just `client.DownloadFile(uri, fileName)` not `await client.DownloadFile(uri, fileName)` the key word `await` is used on Async methods... so try just `client.DownloadFile(uri, fileName)` if that works... then you can research `Async`

Comment: @Seabizkit i Tryed That But Not Working I Tryed Many Method But Still Not Working

Comment: include the name of the target file, is it .zip or .rar

Comment: @Seabizkit  https://workupload.com/start/c2kh9NB This Is Link Its A Test.Zip File

Comment: show what you are putting for the url

Comment: @Seabizkit `string tAddress = "https://workupload.com/start/c2kh9NB";`

Comment: i think ur url is wrong, i think u want https://alioth.workupload.com/download/c2kh9NB, that url is the page load... tricky...its not actually the file itself....

Comment: @Seabizkit can you give me that test.zip currect download link? and i'l Try it

Comment: u not making sense i gave u the url.... check in the download tab in chome.... what the actually url is.... which is the one i gave...."https://workupload.com/start/c2kh9NB" is a link to a page resource not a file resource.. it just looks like its the file as to what the page is doing... see below i see they doing tricky

Comment: https://caph.workupload.com/download/c2kh9NB

Comment: clicking the link in a browser should just download the file... not load a page..

Comment: at the time of writing this link caph.workupload.com/download/c2kh9NB link is valid, but my guess is they may generate this on the fly... to prevent simply consumption. as alioth.workupload.com/download/c2kh9NB was valid, but now load the page instead of file. so i think ur problem is ur tring to consume a 3rd party which has measure in place to prevent you from just downloading in a simply way... this is probably protection from miss-use which they don't want.

Comment: @Seabizkit Yea Its Downloading When I Click Link, I Pasted It In tAddress but Still Not Opening

Comment: create console version i can copy and paste and check what u saying..

Comment: my test i cant get the actual file im just hittin the page, my file size is 12kb, which isnt right are you gettin the right file size?

Comment: try this... yeah looks like what i was saying the site is making it hard....https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60307832/why-doesnt-webrequest-allowautoredirect-redirect-the-initial-url-to-the-correct

Comment: Are the files identical? Can you compare both files with an md5 hash? or a file compare tool?

Comment: @Seabizkit My File Size is 12kb too

Comment: @GuKkA see answer i posted...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

the site is not being friendly maybe on purpose who knows but

if you follow what hes doing here it will work..

[Why doesn't WebRequest.AllowAutoRedirect redirect the initial url to the correct download url?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60307832/why-doesnt-webrequest-allowautoredirect-redirect-the-initial-url-to-the-correct)

Comment: Am Gonna Test Solution

Answer (score 0):

Use a try catch block to spot the exception it throws:

```
try
{
    WebClient client = new WebClient();
        string tAddress = "Download Link"; // When i Downloaded mySelf it Worked And Opened
        string fileName = "Testfile.Zip";
        Uri uri = new Uri(tAddress);
        client.DownloadFileCompleted += Client_DownloadFileCompleted;
        client.DownloadFileAsync(uri, fileName);
}
catch(Excepction ex)
{
    MessageBox.Show(ex.Message)
}
```

Its possible that the problem is in Client.DownloadFileAsync() in that case use the method : "ZipFile.Open" 
Also, for rar try this: https://stackoverflow.com/a/11523864/12764752

Comment: Same Problem Downloading But Not Opening.